Why are Mexicans protesting the judicial reform with PJF banners?
During the recent protests in Mexico, I saw several T-shirts and banners praising [the] 'PJF'.


Is this the Federal Judicial Police that according to Wikipedia "was shut down in 2002 due to its own rampant corruption and criminal activity"? Seem like a long time ago to be an issue anymore? Or are those sarcastic banners?

This is probably a reference to the Poder Judicial de la Federación, the Federal Judicial Power (or Judicial Power of the Federation).
As can be read in this article:

Magistrados, jueces, estudiantes y trabajadores del Poder Judicial de
la Federación expresan dicha incertidumbre por el dictamen final de la
reforma judicial y al respecto, en distintos puntos del país mantienen
las protestas. Sigue aquí el avance de las demonstrations alrededor
de la República.

That is:

Magistrates, judges, students and workers of the Federal Judicial Power express the aforementioned uncertainty over the final pronouncement of the judicial reform, and as such, they maintain protests in various parts of the country. Follow the news of the protests around the Republic here.


I see. Different PJF.
